# UDP hole-punch explanation

Tags: networking, udp, hole-punching

I'm trying to understand UDP hole punching and I just don't quite get it.
In concept it seems simple but when I put it into practice I can't pull it off.
From what I understand there's a public server we call the hole-punch server. A client makes a request to hole-punch server (this is public). The hole-punch server spits out a public ip and port of the client that just made the request. So long as that port is open then essentially any random client can make a request to that client using that specific port and ip ?

The issue I guess I'm having is, the client is able to make a request to the server. The server is able to send data back to the client on that public port and ip however when another client tries to send a request to that client using that same port and ip it just doesn't go through and that's what's confusing me. If the server can make the request why can't another random client make that request?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The thing to know about UDP hole-punching is that many consumer-grade Internet routers/NAT-firewalls have a policy along the lines of "block any incoming UDP packets, *except* for UDP packets coming from an IP address that the user's local computer has recently sent a UDP packet to"; the idea being that if the local user is sending packets to a particular IP address, then the packets coming back from that same IP address are probably legitimate/desirable.

So in order to get UDP packets flowing between two firewalled/NAT'd computers, you have to get each of the two computers to first send a UDP packet to the other one; which is a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem since they can't know where to send the UDP packet without being able to communicate; the public server is what solves that problem.  Since that server is public, both clients can communicate with the server (via UDP or TCP or HTTP or whatever), and that server can tell each client the IP address and port to send its UDP packets to.  Once each client has sent some initial packets to the other, it should also (in most cases) then be able to receive UDP packets from the other client as well, at which point the server is no longer necessary as a go-between.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So the question I have is would I create a new socket for the new public address and port or keep the same socket I'm using to communicate to the server? Or does it not matter?

Comment: For UDP, one socket is enough to send and receive to/from anywhere (using sendto() and recvfrom()).  For TCP you need a separate socket for each host you want to connect to.

Comment: My understanding is different from the "text book hole punching": Basically you need communication with a mediator (public server) to know about public dynamic socket addresses of each node. From this routing to common public network + firewall rules are already set for each node. Second step is exchange of the socket addresses. Third step is p2p communication and forgetting the mediator. "Hole Punching" is already done in the first step. There is no rejection of packets at any time.

Comment: @SamGinrich if the firewall/NAT is programmed to reject incoming packets from any IP address that it hasn't recently send an outgoing packet to, then client A will need to send at least one outgoing packet to client B's IP address in order to invoke that behavior.  Whether that first outgoing packet gets rejected or not will depend on whether the firewall/NAT at guarding client B has already done the same thing, but it's likely that whichever client performs that step first will find that its first outgoing packet doesn't get through the other client's firewall (not that it needs to)

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner Basically you don't know the counterparts sockets address and at this point a scenario with just nodes A and B is not realistic. Have you thought about this?

Comment: @SamGinrich I think we are talking past each other.  You know the counterpart's socket address via the mediator/server.  A scenario without a mediator/server is indeed unrealistic, that's why the mediator/server is necessary.

Comment: @Jeremy Just want to understand fully. May be I considered a special technical solution, where the Datagram Sockets, which do the mediator communication are re-used for P2P and for these the ports should already be open at the firewalls. May be my assumption does not apply with asymmetric routing and your scenario still does.

Comment: It’s true that a datagram socket can be reused to send/receive packets from anywhere; but the firewalls don’t know/care which socket was used to send UDP packets; they do their filtering based solely on the source and destination fields of the UDP packets they receive.

Comment: That's precisely the point: Some (NAT-) fiterwalls filter by port only, others also care about the remote endpoint